# Библиотека FLTK

Tags: c++

Собрал библиотеку FLTK. Пытаюсь её протестировать. Указал доп. библиотеки: fltkd.lib wsock32.lib comctl32.lib fltkjpegd.lib fltkimagesd.lib. И указал игнорировать libcd.lib. Тестю вот этим кодом:

```
#include <FL/Fl.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Box.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Window.H>

int main()
{
Fl_Window window(200, 200, "Window title");
Fl_Box box(0, 0, 200, 200, "HELLO WORLD!");
window.show();
return Fl::run();
}
```

Линковщик выдает вот это:

> 1>------ Сборка начата: проект: FLTK_TEST, Конфигурация: Debug Win32
>   ------ 1>fltkd.lib(Fl_Box.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall Fl_Box::Fl_Box(int,int,int,int,char const *)"
>   (??0Fl_Box@@QAE@HHHHPBD@Z) уже определен в main.obj
>   1>C:\Users\nail1\source\repos\FLTK_TEST\Debug\FLTK_TEST.exe : fatal
>   error LNK1169: обнаружен многократно определенный символ - один или
>   более 1>Сборка проекта "FLTK_TEST.vcxproj" завершена с ошибкой.
>   ========== Сборка: успешно: 0, с ошибками: 1, без изменений: 0, пропущено: 0 ==========

Comment: попробуйте инклуды заголовков _#include <FL/Fl_Box.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Window.H>_ поменять местами.

Comment: Совершенно непонятно, откуда могло взяться определение `Fl_Box` в main... У этого проекта вообще не должно быть доступа к реализации (которая в статической библиотеке), только к заголовкам. Вы случаем не клали исходники fltk в свой проект как-то?

Comment: Нет, не клал. ()

Comment: Просто создаю пустой проект.